# Parametric line equation that fits three-dimensional vectors

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

we have two lines:

$L_{1}: x=1+t_{1}, y=t_{1}, z=2-5t_{1}$

$L_{2}: x=-1+t_{1}, y=2+t_{2}, z=1-{t}_{2}$

where ${t}_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ are scalars. $L_{1}$ crosses the $xz$-plane in point $P$ and $L_{2}$ crosses the $yz$-plane in point $Q$. the question then continues to ask for plane and line equation....

My question is that someone started to answer this by saying vector1 to be $\langle1,1,-5\rangle$ and vector 2 to be $\langle-1,2,0\rangle$

How did they get vector 2?

Comment: Crossing xz plane means $y = 0$. Not sure how either of those points appear though.

Comment: So, what are "vector1" and "vector2"? These are certainly not $P$ or $Q$.

Comment: I think we're supposed to find P & Q. this person who answered the question was able to find v1, v2 then they cross product v1Xv2 to find plane equation  10(x-1)+3(y-0)+3(2-z)=0

Comment: vector1 is coefficients of t1. but i don't know about vector2

Comment: P is (1, 0, 2) because y = $t_1$ = 0.